# Не корректно работает Шифр с использованием букв

Tags: python

Делаю шифр с помощью букв из строчки ввода. Для текста, который состоит из одного слова шифрует верно, но если их несколько или встречаются большие буквы - начинаются не точности. Как возможно исправить?!

```
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    sys.exit("Ошибка")

key = (sys.argv[1])
for k in key:
    if not k.isalpha():
        sys.exit("Ошибка")
        
index = 0
chiper = ""
text = input ("Исходный: ")
for c in text:
    if c in string.ascii_lowercase and string.ascii_uppercase:
        offset = ord(key[index]) - ord('a')
        
        encrypted_c = chr((ord(c) - ord('a') + offset) %26 + ord('a'))
        chiper = chiper + encrypted_c
        
        index = (index + 1) % len(key)
        
    else:
        chiper = chiper + c
    
print ("Шифр: " + chiper)
```

Comment: замените `if c in string.ascii_lowercase and string.ascii_uppercase` на `if c in string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase`

Comment: Немного добавлю комментарий @n1tr0xs. В вашем текущем условии сначала выполняется проверка **if c in string.ascii_lowercase** и потом **if string.ascii_uppercase** . То есть, результатом второго условия будет булевое значение, которое всегда будет True.

Comment: Вроде лучше, но к сожалению не сохраняется (корректен) режим шифра при использовании больших букв...(

Comment: Допустим слово BaR при ключе "BaZ"  должно быть CaQ, а не qae...

Comment: какой шифр вы пытаетесь реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из-за того, что символы нижнего и верхнего регистра располагаются не подряд приходится проверять какого регистра мы шифруем.
Вот так нужно изменить цикл `for` чтобы работало как вы хотите:

```
for c in text:
    if c not in (string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase):
        chiper +=  c
        continue

    if key[index].islower():
        offset = ord(key[index]) - ord('a')
    else:
        offset = ord(key[index]) - ord('A')

    if c.islower():
        encrypted_c = chr((ord(c) - ord('a') + offset) %26 + ord('a'))       
    else:
        encrypted_c = chr((ord(c) - ord('A') + offset) %26 + ord('A'))

    chiper += encrypted_c
    index = (index + 1) % len(key)
```

И можно немного сократить код вот так:

```
for c in text:
    if c not in (string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase):
        chiper +=  c
        continue

    offset = ord(key[index]) - (ord('a') if key[index].islower() else ord('A'))
    _ord = ord('a') if c.islower() else ord('A')
        
    encrypted_c = chr((ord(c) - _ord + offset) %26 + _ord)
    chiper += encrypted_c
    index = (index + 1) % len(key)
```

Что позволит нам избавиться от `continue` без явной вложенности `if`:

```
for c in text:
    if c in (string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase):
        offset = ord(key[index]) - (ord('a') if key[index].islower() else ord('A'))
        _ord = ord('a') if c.islower() else ord('A')
            
        encrypted_c = chr((ord(c) - _ord + offset) %26 + _ord)
        chiper += encrypted_c
        index = (index + 1) % len(key)
    else:
        chiper += c
```

Comment: Да, спасибо...!